# Uncaught ReferenceError: *function here* is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, mediawiki, referenceerror

> Uncaught ReferenceError: limitText is not defined

Just from the number of matching results, I see numerous other people have had this issue - Though the solution runs on a case-by-case basis.

This is basically a function for telling you how many character you have left in a given form as you type - "You have XXX character left".

Javascript:

```
"use strict"; // <-- This was a suggested remedy, did nothing.
function limitText(limitField, limitCount, limitNum) {
    if (limitField.value.length > limitNum) {
        limitField.value = limitField.value.substring(0, limitNum);
    } else {
        limitCount.value = limitNum - limitField.value.length;
    }
}
```

HTML (Unrelated PHP omitted):

```
<textarea name="BlogPost" maxlength="5000" cols="100" rows="20" 
onKeyDown="limitText(this.form.BlogPost,this.form.countdown,5000);" 
      onKeyUp="limitText(this.form.BlogPost,this.form.countdown,5000);" required></textarea>
   <font size="1">(Maximum characters: 5000)<br>
   You have <input readonly type="text" name="countdown" size="3" value="5000">
   characters left.</font>
```

Putting my browser into "Debug Mode" actually causes the script to work without error - Though I genuinely cannot expect any user running the app to do the same. It also works if the script is placed directly into the document with `<script></script>`, though the system I'm working with scolds that as being "bad practice" as you're expected to load scripts through it's fancy module system. (Mediawiki)

Any ideas?

Comment: Is the script tag at the top of the body or in the head?

Comment: Are you sure the script is being loaded before the textarea is used?

Comment: Make sure `limitText` is in global scope or use a different method to bind the event handlers: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html . You get the error because either you have a syntax error and the code cannot be executed or because the function is not in global scope.

Comment: Right now it's in the top, though I've tried both and it makes no difference. @wbennett - Yes.

Comment: Where is limitText defined? Is it in some .js file?

Comment: @Mariatta - It's defined in the above Javascript, which is contained in it's own file.

Comment: Show us the code that loads the script in which `limitText` is defined. It is probably not in the global scope.

Comment: Your html file should have something like this <script type="text/javascript" src="javascriptfilename.js"> where `limitText` is defined inside javascriptfilename.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First iteration with `onKeyDown` and `onKeyUp` (you missed **form** element) – http://jsfiddle.net/3ZAeP/

**code**

```
(function (global) {
    global.limitText = limitText;
    function limitText(limitField, limitCount, limitNum) {
        if (limitField.value.length > limitNum) {
            limitField.value = limitField.value.substring(0, limitNum);
        } else {
            limitCount.value = limitNum - limitField.value.length;
        }
    }
}(window));
```

It's interesting as `limitText` should be global out of box.

Comment: I'm still baffled by this! I was close to chucking my laptop out the window over this *minor* frustration. Thank-you for your answer, this had the entire Mediawiki IRC stumped.